# React Error: Too many re-renders with MaterialTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-table

I'm using a MaterialTable for user to input data and then check if the Rods numbers are valid (1, 2, 3...) in App.tsx. If they are valid, I draw the rods, otherwise I want to throw an error. Everything's fine when i input rods correctly, but it shoots errors when i input them in wrong order. I understand the problem is when i use setAreRodsOk(false), but i don't know how to fix it.

App.tsx

```
interface RodsData {
  i: number; 
  L: number;  
  A: number; 
  E: number; 
  S: number; 
  q: number; 
}

function App() {
  const [dataRods, setDataRods] = useState<Array<RodsData>>([])
  const changeDataRods = (data: Array<RodsData>) => {setDataRods(data)}
  const [dataLoads, setDataLoads] = useState<Array<Object>>([])
  const changeDataLoads = (data: Array<Object>) => {setDataLoads(data)}

  const [areRodsOK, setAreRodsOk] = useState<Boolean>(true);
  for (let j: number = 1; j <= dataRods.length; j++) {
    let isOK = dataRods.find((val) => val.i === j);
    if (!isOK) {
     setAreRodsOk(false);
     break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
      <Header />
        <Switch>

          <Route exact path='/'>
            <HomePage />
          </Route>

          <Route path='/pre'>
            <div className="Preprocessor">
              <div className="tables margin">
                <RodsTable data={dataRods}  setData={changeDataRods}/>
                <LoadsTable data={dataLoads} setData={changeDataLoads}/>
              </div>
              {areRodsOK ?
              <Konva data={dataRods} />
              : (
                <Alert className="alert" severity="error">
                  {' '}
                  <AlertTitle>Ошибка!</AlertTitle> Неправильная нумерация стержней{' '}
                </Alert>)}
            </div>
          </Route>

          <Route path='/pro'>
            <h1>Processor</h1>
          </Route>

          <Route path='/post'>
            <h1>Postprocessor</h1>
          </Route>

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

RodsTable.js

```
export default function LastHope(props) {
  return (
      <div className="TableRods">
        <MaterialTable
          columns={[
            {
              title: 'Rod number',
                    field: 'i',
                    type: 'numeric',
                    filtering: false,
              align: 'center',
            },
            /-- more columns --/
           ]}

          data={props.data}
          title="Стержни"
          icons={{
            Add: props => <AddIcon />,
            Edit: props => <EditIcon />,
            Delete: props => <DeleteIcon />,
            Clear: props => <DeleteIcon />,
            Check: props => <CheckIcon />,
            Search: props => <SearchIcon />,
            ResetSearch: props => <DeleteIcon />
          }}

          editable={{
            onRowAdd: newData => {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  props.setData([...props.data, newData]);
  
                  resolve();
                }, 1000);
              })},

            onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  const dataUpdate = [...props.data];
                  const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                  dataUpdate[index] = newData;
                  props.setData([...dataUpdate]);

                  resolve();
                }, 1000);
              }),

            onRowDelete: oldData =>
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  const dataDelete = [...props.data];
                  const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                  dataDelete.splice(index, 1);
                  props.setData([...dataDelete]);

                  resolve();
                }, 1000);
              })
          }}
        />
        </div>
  );
}
```

[The picture of mistake should help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE99e.png)

Fixed code will be really appreciated, thank's in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason to use state for areRodsOK? Could that just be a variable?

Comment: @BenStephens Man, I feel so stupid right now. I never thought of this. Thank`s for help.